# regex to mask certain field

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string like below :

```
{5b4888ad-53cc-4fa8-9e0f-dbb339b238fd={NETFLOW_IP=[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2], SNMP_COMMUNITY=[public], SNMP_TRAP_IP=[1.1.1.1]}}
```

I want a final string :

```
{5b4888ad-53cc-4fa8-9e0f-dbb339b238fd={NETFLOW_IP=[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2], SNMP_COMMUNITY=[****], SNMP_TRAP_IP=[1.1.1.1]}}
```

I am trying String :

```
replacedMapStr = mapStr.replaceAll("(?<=SNMP_COMMUNITY=).*?(?=})", "****");
```

but it is truncating all character after  `SNMP_COMMUNITY`

I want to mask the value of `SNMP_COMMUNITY` field. `SNMP_COMMUNITY` can have any value.

Comment: You should try to match the string between `[` and `]` instead of matching `.*`. I do not provide a regex for that as I do not know the format of this part, but a \w may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close try to change `.*?(?=})` with `\\[.*?\\]` like so :

```
String replacedMapStr = mapStr.replaceAll("(?<=SNMP_COMMUNITY=)\\[.*?\\]", "[****]");
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^    ^    ^
```

Output

```
{5b4888ad-53cc-4fa8-9e0f-dbb339b238fd={NETFLOW_IP=[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2], SNMP_COMMUNITY=[****], SNMP_TRAP_IP=[1.1.1.1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I love all the different answers to regex questions, here is mine, with explanation:

```
replacedMapStr = mapStr.replaceAll("SNMP_COMMUNITY=\[[^\]]*\]", "SNMP_COMMUNITY=[****]");
```

The regex in in parts:

- SNMP_COMMUNITY=
- Literally these characters in a row
- \[
- A left bracket
- [^\]]*
- This is the magic to avoiding using `?`.  This is a negated character class that contains a right bracket.  The meaning here is "Any number of characters that aren't right brackets.  So you can see that the scanner will simply move forward until it finds a right bracket.  The backslash is in there to show that we mean a right bracket character and not to end the character class.
- ]
- The right bracket

Comment: I think at least some regex implementations won't actually need that backslash and can parse [^]] correctly. GNU Grep for one.